# How to send a mysql query from a php form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm creating a php web page and I need to send a mysql query with the form parameters. 
Query I need to send:

```
INSERT INTO News (Titolo_news,Contenuto_news) VALUES
         ('*title from form*','*content from form*');
```

This is my actual code:

```
<?php
...

<form class="action="#" method='POST'>

  <p>Title:<input name="title" required id="title" /></p>
  <p>Content:<input name="content" required id="content" /></p>
  <button class="login-button" type="submit" title="Confirm" onclick="

        QUERY HERE, RIGHT?

  ">Confirm</button>

</form>

...
?>
```

Comment: You **don't** you send your form data to a script that in turn will make a query against your database.

Comment: There is very little here, and while this is tagged php, there is no php in your script, just an sql query and some html.  I suggest reading up on some tutorials

Answer (score 4):

You **should not** be exposing queries on the frontend in html/javascript. There can be times you could do it but it is bad practice. The client that sends the form could change the query for instance. They could find all your databases and drop them all.

What you should do is pass through the values you want for your query and sanitise the data you receive.

Your form sends the values of the title and content and your server side code receives the data, makes sure they are ok to store, the right data type etc. and runs your query inserting the data. In php you could use `PDO` or `MySQLi` to help with this by using prepared statements.

Here is a rough example that is not robust, more for illustration:

```
<?php
// configuration
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "admin";

// database connection
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

// form was submitted
if(isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['content'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];

    // add more validation and sanitising if required

    // query using prepared statements
    $sql = "INSERT INTO News (Titolo_news,Contenuto_news) VALUES
     (:title, :content)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array(':title'=>$title,
                  ':content'=>$content));
?>

<p>Thanks for submitting the form</p>

<?php
} else {
    // form not submitted so show the form
?>

<form class="" action="#" method='POST'>
  <label>Title</label><input name="title" required id="title" />
  <label>Content:</label><input name="content" required id="content" />
  <button class="login-button" type="submit" title="Confirm">Confirm</button>
</form>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Comment: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: I didn't use your query so i have just edited it. Could you try again, I suspect that was the problem.

Comment: Still: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object

Comment: I'm not sure why it is failing exactly. Do you know what line it has the error on?. As i said it is not a robust example, it lacks all error checking. Could you try running `SHOW COLUMNS FROM News`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the theory, first the issues.

- You are using an onclick event handler which executes JavaScript rather than PHP code, you need to send the request server side to make this happen. To do that use a submit button rather than just button i.e
  `<input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="confirmation">`. Note that ive added the value and name attributes, these are the attributes that are sent to the backend for further processing. Depending on the type of form submission you can access them with GET, POST or REQUEST. Here is a link for more info http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
- Where does the query go? It isnt going to be part of the form, logically when someone submits the form, you want the request to be processed and then some sort of message to be displayed ABOVE/BEFORE the form. This means that you want the query processing above the form rather than below it.
- we need to make sure if the page is rendered it doesnt process that query because the form isnt submitted. To do that you would have to place a conditional which will encapsulate the query statement. This is the `if(isset...` statement.

Since you are using PHP to run the query, you wont be able to write the raw query i.e `INSERT INTO...`, you would need to use a driver for the database to connect to it and then run the query. If using MySQL then use the following link for more info. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

So at the end your form would be something like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['confirmation'])) {
  // Connect to database
  // Run the query
  // Display a message that it was successful or not
}

<form class="action="#" method='POST'>

    <p>Title:<input name="title" required id="title" /></p>
    <p>Content:<input name="content" required id="content" /></p>
    <button class="login-button" type="submit" title="Confirm">Confirm</button>

</form>

...
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you wanna do. Anyway, if I understood correctly, you can use the Zakaria Acharki solution that uses input hidden or use AJAX to pass that query to a php file, let's use the input hidden since I think you don't know anything about AJAX.
Here the code, I made also some correction:

```
<script>
myfunc() {
   var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
   var content = document.getElementById('content').value;
   var query = 'INSERT INTO News (Titolo_news,Contenuto_news) VALUES
     (title, content);';
   document.getElementsById("query")[0].setAttribute("value", query);
}
</script>

<form action="#" method='POST'>

  <p>Title:<input name="title" required id="title" /></p>
  <p>Content:<input name="content" required id="content" /></p>
  <input class="login-button" type="submit" value="Confirm" onclick="myfunc()" />
  <input type='hidden' id='query' name="query" value="" />

</form>

<?php
 $query = $_POST['query'];
?>
```

My final advise to you is to study more, don't do things like you think they should be done when you didn't study yet.
To understand why what you want to do is completely wrong read the answer of Ad Proc that seems to me quite exhaustive.

Answer (score -2):

you can use it

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
     $title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
INSERT INTO News (Titolo_news,Contenuto_news) VALUES ('$title', '$content');
}
```

Comment: Okay but I want the query to be sent when I press the form button

Comment: Since my html code is inside an echo i got this error: Notice: Undefined index: submit

Comment: give name to input type="submit" to name="submit"

Comment: @priya786, your answer is a bit confusing since it's not syntactically correct. You can edit it to improve it.